# Generation Apk Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, apk

I have an error when i want to create APK, please help me ?

Build at: 2021-03-26T18:46:10.897Z - Hash: 7c6bf6a761ede9369f11 - Time: 23007ms

> cordova.cmd build android
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\jmunozo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\jmunozo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
> Using Android SDK: C:\Users\jmunozo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 16s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not receive a message from the daemon.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\jmunozo\myApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\jmunozo\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle
  [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

  ```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ```